# GSEventLockDevice couldn't Lock phone properly

Tags: iphone, ios

I locked the iPhone by calling the method `GSEventLockDevice()`from `GraphicsServices.framework`. It's working fine on the iPhone , but after locking the phone the backlight doesn't turn off. It remains lit and it shows the unlock screen.

How can I make the screen turn off immediately after locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this. Apple never accept this kind of private framework tasks. It must be jailbreak app. GraphicsServices.framework not deals with backlight and screen ON and OFF state. it just deals with GSEvents and other graphical things. I think you can't do that .

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for a jailbroken phone you could use `GSEventSetBacklightLevel(0);` to dim the brightness level.